# NRPE Firewall blocking xinetd

Tags: windows, firewall, connection, nrpe, xinetd

From one side, my nagios server, IP *10.1.1.232.*
Here is my Nagios's xinetd's NRPE config :

```
# default: on
# description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream
        port            = 5666
        wait            = no
        user            = nagios
        server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 10.1.1.232 10.1.1.132 10.1.1.220
}
```

Firewall : at this point DEACTIVATED

(else is permissive for local network on the 5666 port (NRPE))

---

From the other side, my computer, IP *10.1.1.132*. Here is the xinetd's NRPE config (using winrpe, who work fine before i got this problem) :

```
# default: on
# description: NRPE
service nrpe
{
type = UNLISTED
flags = REUSE
port = 5666
socket_type = stream        
wait = no
user = SvcXinet
server = /bin/nrpe
server_args = -c /nrpe.cfg --inetd
log_on_failure += USERID
disable = no
only_from       = 10.1.1.232 10.1.1.132 10.1.1.220
# only_from       = <ipaddress1> <ipaddress2> ...
}
```

The service windows xinetd is STARTED. There is a rule in the firewall who permitt connexion from 10.1.1.232 on the 5666 port.

---

From 10.1.1.232 :

```
./check_nrpe -H 10.1.1.232
NRPE v2.15
./check_nrpe -H 10.1.1.132
CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.
```

---

From 10.1.1.132 :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\winrpe\bin>check_nrpe.exe -H 10.1.1.132
connect to address 10.1.1.132 port 5666: Connection refused
connect to host 10.1.1.132 port 5666: Connection refused

C:\Program Files (x86)\winrpe\bin>check_nrpe.exe -H 10.1.1.232
NRPE v2.15
```

---

### So we have :

```
[.132] ---> [.132] ==> NOT WORKING : connection refused (explicable by the firewall, who permit only from .232
[.132] ---> [.232] ==> OK
[.232] ---> [.232] ==> OK
[.232] ---> [.132] ==> NOT WORKING : timeout
```

With wireshark, i've seen a tcp replication when i make .232 --> .132 (so not handle by my computer

How can i fix that ?

Comment: NRPE + xinetd on Windows? That sounds scary. Have you had a look on NSClient? It also supports the NRPE protocol.

Comment: Yes, i've already looked for this, but have to work with Winrpe, who propose some good features and plugins

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was strange, i've started the service from services.msc, that showed me that the service is running, but in fact, it was not.. By task manager, the service xinetServer was offline. SO i've started it and everithing seems to be good, even the [.132] ---> [.132] who i suspected the firewall, but who did not pass the windows firewall effectively.